# maven include testOutputDirectory in the jar

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Want to add the testoutputdirectory files in the project jar. Tried using below but, the test classes were not included in the jar

What need to be changed to include the same in the project jar?

Using below in the pom.xml

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>test/classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
            </resources>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${final.name}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptor>./src/main/resources/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>   

     .........
</build>
```

Below I have in the assembly.xml

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0         http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

<moduleSets>
    <moduleSet>
        <sources>
            <fileSets>
                <fileSet>
                    <directory>.</directory>
                    <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>test/classes/**/*.class</include>
                    </includes>
                </fileSet>
            </fileSets>
        </sources>
    </moduleSet>
</moduleSets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Why would you like to have test classes in your jar? Would you like to create a test-jar file?

Comment: This is temporary thing but, for now I need to package the test classes as well into the project jar itself. How can I get them into the project jar?

Comment: and the test classes has to be in the testoutputdirectory

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is a good idea to do that at all. Maybe think about to create a separate test-jar. You can do it with the [maven-jar-plugin test-jar goal](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/create-test-jar.html)

Nonetheless, if you really want to do that, you can achieve it by setting the 
`testOutputDirectory` like:

```
<build>
    <testOutputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</testOutputDirectory>
</build>
```

The Tests.java are then compiled to target/classes and from there the maven-jar-plugin packages them to the jar.

Comment: thank you for the response. The test output directory is <testOutputDirectory>test/classes</testOutputDirectory> as mentioned above. How can I include this in the jar?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help.

I was able to include the testoutputdirectory to the jar using the below.

```
<build>
    <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
    <testOutputDirectory>test/classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>

           </resources>
    <plugins>
                      <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>${final.name}</finalName>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptors>
                    <descriptor>src/main/resources/assembly/assembly.xml</descriptor>
                </descriptors>
                <!-- descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs-->
                <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
      .......
     </plugins>
     ..........
</build>




<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/ASSEMBLY/2.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-2.0.0.xsd">

<id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
<baseDirectory>/</baseDirectory>
<formats>
    <format>jar</format>
</formats>
<fileSets>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>./target/classes/</directory>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
    <fileSet>
        <directory>.</directory>
        <outputDirectory></outputDirectory>
        <includes>
            <include>test/classes/**/*.class</include>
        </includes>
    </fileSet>
</fileSets>    
<dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
    </dependencySet>
</dependencySets>
</assembly>
```